# Prevent Stepping into "memory" during Visual studio debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to prevent debugging into std library or runtime classes while debugging my code. Using VS 2013, this is managed C++/CLI. Usually on steps using Strings, the program steps into files like "memory", "gcroot" etc. There seems to be a related thread here, [Visual Studio Debugging- I just want to step through my program!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575621/visual-studio-debugging-i-just-want-to-step-through-my-program), but it no longer seems to work in VS 2013.

I have these lines in my natfilter.

```
<Function><Name>ATL::CHeapPtrBase.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
  <Function><Name>ATL::CHeapPtrBase.*::_Get</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
  <Function><Name>ATL::CHeapPtrBase.*::_Get*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
```

But it still steps into memory's

```
_Ty *_Get() const
{   // return pointer to resource
    return (_Ptr);
}
```

when it passes through a line containing a String^. Similar behaviour for xstring while using std::string.

It is quite distracting during debugging. Anyone noticed this or know of a way to prevent this in VS 2013..

Comment: Have a try at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I have just my code option selected and .net framework source stepping deselected in debugging options.. But it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score -1):

While debugging you have options: Step In and Step Over. Use the latter for the statements for which you do not want to debug internals.

Comment: It is not always possible.. eg. this statement **`auto inst = process::Write(inst->ToString());`** . I want to step into the Write method and not have to step into memory, string for the arguments. a breakpoint would help but will too many in case of line by line debugging.

Comment: Try conditional breakpoint. Set a breakpoint, right click on it and select option to set condition. The breakpoint will be hit only when the condition is true.

Comment: it could work, but i have like 50-60 lines in a method (almost all with string processing) and usually step through 10-15 before running it through.. Setting 10-15 breakpoints with conditions specified seems like lot of additional work.. (similar methods are there in other classes. i would need to do these again in those classes).